# Как реализовать в боте телеграмм на php, что бы он отвечал, только тогда когда ему пишут в ответном сообщении?

Tags: php, telegram-bot, бот

Есть данный код, в данном коде, бот отвечает рандомным текстом $rr в ответ написанному мною сообщению, а нужно что бы бот отвечал мне когда, я напишу в ответ на бота сообщение! Подскажите как реализовать?!

```
<?php

define('API_KEY','тут токен');

function bot($method,$datas=[]){
    $url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot".API_KEY."/".$method;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($datas));
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    if(curl_error($ch)){
        var_dump(curl_error($ch));
    }else{
        return json_decode($res);
    }
}

$update = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
$message = $update->message;
$message_id = $update->message->id;
$chat_id = $message->chat->id;
$name = $from_id = $message->from->first_name;
$from_id = $message->from->id;
$text = $message->text;
$fromid = $update->callback_query->from->id;
$username = $update->message->from->username;
$chatid = $update->callback_query->message->chat->id;
$callback_query = $update->callback_query->data;
$messageid = $update->callback_query->message->message_id;
$reply = $update->message->reply_to_message->message_id;

if ($update->message){
  bot('sendChatAction',[
    'chat_id'=>$update->message->chat->id,
    'action'=>'typing'
  ]);
  bot('sendMessage',[
    'chat_id'=>$update->message->chat->id,
    'text'=>$rr,
    'parse_mode'=>'markdown',
    'disable_web_page_preview'=>'false',
    'reply_to_message_id'=>$update->message->message_id
  ]);
      exit('ok');
}
    ex
```

добавил такой код:

```
$reply_author = $update->message->reply_to_message->from->id;

if (isset($reply_author) && $update->message){
  bot('sendMessage',[
    'chat_id'=>$update->message->chat->id,
    'text'=>$rg,
    'parse_mode'=>'markdown',
    'reply_to_message_id'=>$update->message->message_id
  ]);
      exit('ok');
}
```

теперь если писать в ответ, он отвечает, НО если я в чате пишу в ответ не боту, а другому кому то он так же отвечает, а мне нужно что бы он отвечал когда я буду писать именно данному боту в ответ!

Comment: Если у вас первое сообщение отсылает бот, на которое вы потом отвечаете, то сравнивайте ID бота с $reply_author.

Comment: Бот работает в чат группе, там куча сообщений как от других пользователей таки от ботов!